# Cannot open blocks, pages via Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2.3, cms-block, cms-pages

I have installed Magento 2.3 on xampp. I have tried to check the CMS pages, blocks via admin panel but its not opening instead it says the error

> Attention, Something went wrong

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was permissions on the Notifications

[image]

**ALSO**

Based on [ https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6602 ] you can:

- uninstall the Magento and install it again.
  **[OR]**
- go to database, find ui_bookmark table, delete all entries

**ALSO**

You should check the `var/logs` folder to see if something went wrong and also your server logs.

For me the issue was related to this one https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5418.

Gone into db table cataloginventory_stock_item and delete duplicates and then the issue dissapeared.

If that doesn't solve it, you can try:

1) cd into `pub/static` and run `find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete`

2) cd into root folder and run `rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/`

3) run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

If this doesn't solve it you could take the radical option to reinstall:

1) delete the vendor folder `rm -rf vendor/*` and also the `composer.lock` file in root.

2) run `composer install`